# Ubuntu16.04 hangs on shutdown/reboot after NIS client setting

Tags: 16.04, nis

I tried to configure NIS client. but, My ubuntu took a time to shutdown/reboot after "/etc/nsswitch.conf" setting.

nis version

```
3.17-34ubuntu3
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         nis compat
group:          nis compat
shadow:         nis compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns nis
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

journalctl log of hang part

```
Jan 15 16:06:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped target Network is Online.
Jan 15 16:06:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped target Network.
Jan 15 16:06:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Raise network interfaces...
Jan 15 16:07:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Stopping timed out.Terminating.
Jan 15 16:07:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Raise network interfaces.
Jan 15 16:07:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 15 16:07:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 15 16:07:48 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
```

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm running into the same problem